# Summary statistic of variance across measurements with different units

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics

I'm looking to calculate a metric that summarizes variance for multiple characters among repeated observations for different groups. Say you measure height, width, and weight among four different populations of gremlins, is there a way you could come up with a single metric that describes 'total' variance among all the characters measured for each population?

Here is an example using the iris data set from R. I'm sure this is incorrect, but it approximates what I'm looking for...

```
data(iris)

iris_var <- aggregate(.~Species, iris, var)

iris_var_scaled <- apply(scale(iris_var[-1]), 2, function(x) x-min(x))

iris_var_scaled_byspecies <- apply(iris_var_scaled, 1, sum)

names(iris_var_scaled_byspecies) <- iris_var$Species

iris_var_scaled_byspecies
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in R, but your question made think about the 
[coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation).

With it, you could compare if the relative standard deviation would differ between groups.

Edit: following the comment by mkt, I'll add two specific alternatives that can be used and are related with the variance:

- Compute the coefficient of variation over each group for of each variable e.g., something like:
  $$
  \frac{\bar{h}}{s_h} \quad \textrm{and} \quad \frac{\bar{l}}{s_l} \quad \textrm{and} \quad \frac{\bar{w}}{s_w}
  $$
  where the overbar means the mean of the group for that variable and $s$ stands for the sample standard deviation (and I've used $h$ for height, $l$ for width and $w$ for weight as examples).
- Another alternative would be to standardize each value of each variable and then compute the sum of the mean squares of each standardized variables within each group. This is more complex but will give you one number per group.

To do this, we can start by computing the standardized value $z_{g,i,v}$ of variable $v\in\{h,l,w,\ldots\}$ for individual $i$ that belongs to group $g$:
$$
z_{g,i,v} = \frac{x_{g,i,v} - \mu_v}{\sigma_v}
$$
where $x_{g,i,v}$ is the value of variable $v$ of individual $i$ belonging to group $g$, $\mu_v$ is the overall mean of variable $v$ and $\sigma_v$ is the overall standard deviation of variable $v$ (it can be the sample or the population standard deviation, according to your view of the data). By overall I mean computed over all individuals of all groups.

With this, we can compute the mean square $msq$ of the standardized variable $v$ over the $n_g$ individuals that belong to group $g$:
$$
msq_{g,v} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_g} z_{g,i,v}^2}{n_g}
$$

Finally, you could add the mean squares of all variables to have a group measure $M_g = \sum_v msq_{g,v}$.

The comparison between groups would be made by comparing the values of $M_g$, where larger values indicate a larger heterogeneity.

Comment: @mkt I've edited my answer. I believe that I've improved it, but if that is not the case, some feedback is welcome. I'll delete this comment if it's appropriate.

Comment: (+1) Good edit, thanks for the contribution and welcome to the site!